# sharing data across callback functions

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have the following two callback functions. Im wondering is it possible to share the names object between clipname and has_clip functions? This is using the liveapi for ableton, but im sure its just more of a general javascript thing.

```
function loadclips() {

  names = new LiveAPI(this.patcher, 1, clipname, “live_set tracks 0 clip_slots 1 clip”);
  names.property = “name”;

  slot = new LiveAPI(this.patcher, 1, has_clip, “live_set tracks 0 clip_slots 1”);
  slot.property = “has_clip”;

}

function clipname(args) {
  post(args);
}

function has_clip(args) {
  post(args);
}
```

Comment: watch your global scope; `names` is a global but I doubt you want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the safest thing would be to return an object from loadClips (seems sensible too). Make sure to use `var` on new variables. [Global scope pollution](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/) can introduce hard-to-find  bugs.

```
function loadclips() {

  var names = new LiveAPI(this.patcher, 1, clipname, “live_set tracks 0 clip_slots 1 clip”);
  names.property = “name”;

  var slot = new LiveAPI(this.patcher, 1, has_clip, “live_set tracks 0 clip_slots 1”);
  slot.property = “has_clip”;

  return {
    names: names,
    slot: slot
  }; 

}
```

Then pass that into any functions that might need it.

```
function clipname(args, namesAndSlots) {
  // namesAndSlots is available here
  post(args);
}

function has_clip(args, namesAndSlots) {
  // namesAndSlots is available here
  post(args);
}
```

Now you can call loadClips:

```
var namesAndClips = loadClips(); 

var clip = clipName('a', namesAndClips);
```

I think that's closer to what you need anyway.

Comment: I tried this and it seems right, but in the context of ableton it's not working. I cannot get the "slot.property = “has_clip”;" to show up in the clipname function. It just comes through as "undefined"

Comment: try logging the slot object to console after `var slot = new LiveAPI` -- see what is returning from that LiveAPI call

Comment: @Ke. did you get it fixed?